# PlayWright NUnit test: Page object does not get initialized

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, playwright

I'm trying to set up a NUnit Playwright project but I'm having trouble getting the sample test to work.
Either my test does not run or the Page object doesn't get initialized.

[image]

```
﻿ HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 15
   Duration: 196 ms

  Message: 
Test method TelerikWebDesignToolTests.Tests.HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Stack Trace: 
<HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage>d__0.MoveNext() line 17
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

I've tried a few tutorials but for this attempt, I'm following https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro

If I try to run the code verbatim only changing the namespace and adding curly braces to the end of the namespace my test in my "Test Explorer just doesn't run.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TelerikWebDesignToolTests
{


    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
    public class Tests : PageTest
    {
        [Test]
        async public Task HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage()
        {
            await Page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev");

            // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
            await Expect(Page).ToHaveTitleAsync(new Regex("Playwright"));

            // create a locator
            var getStarted = Page.Locator("text=Get Started");

            // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
            await Expect(getStarted).ToHaveAttributeAsync("href", "/docs/intro");

            // Click the get started link.
            await getStarted.ClickAsync();

            // Expects the URL to contain intro.
            await Expect(Page).ToHaveURLAsync(new Regex(".*intro"));
        }
    }
}
```

I can see in the out from "Tests" the reason is:

```
No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=TelerikWebDesignToolTests.Tests.HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage`
```

The only way I could get VS to run the test was by modifying the code to what is seen in the included image. For reference, I've pasted the code below.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TelerikWebDesignToolTests
{


    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests : PageTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        async public Task HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage()
        {
            await Page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev");

            // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
            await Expect(Page).ToHaveTitleAsync(new Regex("Playwright"));

            // create a locator
            var getStarted = Page.Locator("text=Get Started");

            // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
            await Expect(getStarted).ToHaveAttributeAsync("href", "/docs/intro");

            // Click the get started link.
            await getStarted.ClickAsync();

            // Expects the URL to contain intro.
            await Expect(Page).ToHaveURLAsync(new Regex(".*intro"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are mixing up MSTest and NUnit. You need to either use Microsoft.Playwright.MSTest or use `Test` instead of `TestMethod`.